# How to make Call recorder in android studio

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I made a call recorder that works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't work, I searched about it but I can't solve this problem, here is my code:

```
public class RecordingService extends Service {

    private MediaRecorder rec;
    private boolean recorderstarted;
    private File file;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS);

        Date date = new Date();
        CharSequence sdf = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm-ss", date.getTime());

        rec = new MediaRecorder();
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        rec.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + sdf + "rec.3gp");

        MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            public void onError(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Crashed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        rec.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);

        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        manager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
//                super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber){
                if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state
                        && recorderstarted
                ) {
                    Log.i("Hello", "onCallStateChanged: Before stoptel" + (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) );
                    Log.i("Hello", "onCallStateChanged: Before stoprec" + (recorderstarted) );
                    rec.stop();
                    rec.reset();
                    rec.release();
                    recorderstarted = false;
                    stopSelf();
                    Log.i("Hello", "onCallStateChanged: After stoptel" + (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) );
                    Log.i("Hello", "onCallStateChanged: After stoprec" + (recorderstarted) );
                } else if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("Hello", "onCallStateChanged: Before start" + (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state));
                        rec.prepare();
//                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        rec.start();
                        recorderstarted = true;
                        Log.i("Hello", "onCallStateChanged: After start" + (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        return START_STICKY;
//        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

I made this app from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWyvWhG9uJQ), Thanks for taking time to answer my question, if you need code from other class please comment under my question,
I added the runtime permission code and I added the permission code to my `manifest` but my problem was not solved, please help me, Thanks (-:

Comment: call recorder app are being blocked by android devices now a days . if your wanted to recorde calls you want to build Nativ library for it and then use it for Recorder calls. or else you have to register you app as safe app to android device

Comment: How can I register my app as safe app to android device

Comment: i dont know how to

Comment: Can you help me to make a call recorder (-:

Comment: mail me will discuss soon

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You should change AudioSource **VOICE_COMMUNICATION** to **VOICE_CALL**

```
rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
```

To

```
rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL)
```

And add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

into Manifest file. But your app should be as a system app. You can root your phone to make your app as system app or directly add your app to AOSP.